# Writing a Sinatra Extension using options in routes

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Lets say I'm writing a sinatra extension which mounts a second `public` directory at a given mount point.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/moar-public'

set :moar_local, './downloads/'
set :moar_remote, 'dls'
```

I now expect a user going to `http://myapp.com/downloads/thing.bin` to be given the file at `[sinatra_root]/dls/thing.bin`.

Writing this extension (obviously, it's a simplified example) I have something like this:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
module Sinatra
  module MoarPublic
    def self.registered(app)
      app.set :moar_local, './downloads/'
      app.set :moar_remote, 'downloads'

      app.get "/#{app.options.moar_remote}/:filename" do
        # Logic
      end
    end
  end
  register MoarPublic
end
```

But `app.get` has already been called with the default value for `moar_remote` so the download files are available at `/downloads/thing.bin`, not at `/dls/thing.bin` as I'd like. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for dynamic routes, but Sinatra compiles the route information so it won't work the way you're looking for.

As a work around, you might consider defining a catch-all route, and checking the route information inside the catch-all, e.g.

```
get %r{^/(*)/bar$} do |capture|
  if settings.url_prefix == capture # or perhaps check against request.path_info
    # get file
  else
    status 404
  end
end
```

Obviously, there are still many things to be done there, but you get the drift.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this - perfect!

Comment: @JP. Glad it's a help, 2 years late ;D

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem registering an extension explicitily in a modular configuration. Illustration below.

```
class Service < Sinatra::Base
  set :url_prefix, 'foo'
  register Common      
end

module Common
  def self.registered(app)
    app.get "/#{app.options.url_prefix}/bar" do
      "hello world"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately that url_prefix cannot now be overwritten. If you look at [this example](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html#setting_options_and_other_extension_setup) in the Sinatra tutorials, they use the same structure as I have done in my original example (and this appears to be the right way to create an extension), but in doing so `set :url_prefix, 'baz'` won't change the path as it was set when the module was registered.